# Error getting WinPcap address information

Tags: c++, winpcap

Hello i am having some problem getting network card address information from the WinPcap driver. I have noticed that whenever IPv6 is enabled for a particular NIC, the address information for it becomes 0.0.0.0. How can i fix this?

```
pcap_addr* address = GetDeviceAddress(1);

cout<<"IP address "<<iptos(((struct sockaddr_in *)address->addr)->sin_addr.s_addr)<<endl;
/////////////

pcap_addr* GetDeviceAddress(int index)//Gets the name of a device using the zero based index of its location in the list
    {
        int i=0;
            if(pcap_findalldevs_ex(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING,NULL,&AllDevices,errbuf) != -1)
                for(Iterator=AllDevices;Iterator!=NULL;Iterator=Iterator->next)
                {
                    if(i==index)
                    {
                        return Iterator->addresses;
                    }
                i++;
                }
                return NULL;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your code that's looking at the address information look like?  Perhaps it has a bug that causes it not to properly handle IPv6 addresses.

The address information may have *more than one* IP address - libpcap/WinPcap's `pcap_findalldevs()` call and WinPcap's `pcap_findalldevs_ex()` call supply a pointer to a list of `pcap_if_t` structures, one for each interface that it found, and each of those structures includes a *list* of address information items of type `struct pcap_addr`.  Each of those address information items includes a network address, which is of type `struct sockaddr`; that structure includes a member named `sa_family`, which will have the value `AF_INET` for IPv4 and `AF_INET6` for IPv6.  If the member has the value `AF_INET6`, the address data will be 128 bits of IPv6 address, *NOT* 32 bits of IPv4 address.